# strtolower and mb_strtolower doesn't work

Tags: php, string, string-formatting, contao

I have a variable in which a string is stored, which is supplied via an insert tag of the CMS Contao.

```
category = "{{page::title}}";
```

The value of the string is at this point "Fitness" with a big "F". I would like to have this string completely in lowercase letters.

I have already tried the following:

```
// 1
$category = "{{page::title}}";
echo strtolower($category);

// 2
$category = "{{page::title}}";
echo mb_strtolower($category);

// 3
$category = "{{page::title}}";
echo mb_strtolower($category, 'UTF-8');
```

But none of these approaches work and I still get "Fitness" with a big "F".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"{{page::title}}"` is just a string, you achieve nothing by `strtolower`ing it.

Comment: These placeholders have not been replaced by any values at this point - you just lowercased `{{page::title}}` here, and the result of that is obviously the same as it already was. You need to do this after whatever evaluates/parse this kind of templating syntax.

Comment: @u_mulder 
No, Contao provides me with a string with the value "Fitness". So far everything is fine. This is how the insert-tags work in Contao.

Comment: @u_mulder When I echo $ category, I get "Fitness". So the insert-tag works with the quotation marks.

Comment: seems like a cache problem to me...

Comment: It echoes `Fitness` where? It there any templates in this CMS?

Comment: @Johannes Have already emptied the cache several times. Still the same problem.

Comment: @u_mulder 
The result of echo is in the frontend. It's really just about the formatting of the string in lowercase letters. The above code is simply included in <?php ?> within the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert Tags are replaced by Contao before the result is sent to the browser. You are trying to `strtolower` just the insert tag (which does nothing of course) - not the content it will be replaced by.

For your example you can use:

```
global $objPage;
echo strtolower($objPage->pageTitle ?: $objPage->title);
```

or

```
echo strtolower($GLOBALS['objPage']->pageTitle ?: $GLOBALS['objPage']->title);
```

or

```
echo strtolower(\Contao\Controller::replaceInsertTags('{{page::title}}'));
```

Comment: Ok, that's how it works now. But somehow I do not really understand that. I also tried it with a second variable. Unfortunately it did not work. For example: $category = "{{page :: title"}}; $categoryLowercae = strtolower ($category); So it also has to work if contao replaces the tags before the result is send to the browser.

Comment: I don't understand your example. The insert tags are just strings, nothing more. Those strings are then replaced by other strings later on.

Comment: So, $category = "{{page :: title}}" has the value "Fitness". In the next step I create another variable and do $categoryLowerase = strtolower ($category); So I take the first value if $category and format it to lowercase letters. The insert-tag provides me with "Fitness" first, which I save in the first variable and then format it in lowercase letters in the second one. Does not work anyway :)

Comment: Of course it does not work ;). See my answer. Insert tags are just strings, not variables.